# Can't clear the input value after form is submited

Tags: jquery, forms

Ok, I've tried every suggestion that I could find, but those values are still there after submitting form and fadeOut. If anyone has a suggestion...

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#form1').ajaxForm( { beforeSubmit: validate } ); 

function validate(formData, jqForm, options) { 
    var name = $('input[name=name]').fieldValue(); 
    var email = $('input[name=email]').fieldValue(); 
    var message = $('textarea[name=message]').fieldValue(); 

if (!name[0]) { 
alert('Please enter a value for name'); 
return false; 
}  
if (!email[0]) { 
alert('Please enter a value for email'); 
return false; 
}  
if (!message[0]) { 
alert('Please enter a value for message'); 
return false; 
}
}
var name = $('input[name=name]').val(''); 
var email = $('input[name=email]').val('');
var message = $('textarea[name=message]').html(''); 

$("#form1").ajaxForm(function(){
        $("#formplic").fadeOut(1000, function() {
             $(this).html("<img src='images/postauto2.png'/>").fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I've added the suggestions, but it's still not working. Maybe I am not putting them in the right place...?

Comment: I didn't put that code that was not working. Now it is present. But not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: Why it's not working
Read through your script. The suggestion you added (my code) is just a regular statement in the global scope - When the browser loads the file it

1. Sets the document ready method
2. Realizes the function validate
3. **Executes the set-value-to-blank**
4. Sets the ajaxForm value

I'm assuming you want to reset the form after it's been validated (and move on).

In that case, you want the resetting-code to run when the form is done. When is that? Here: `$("#form1").ajaxForm(function(){...`

Someone else has actually given you the exact code (I believe) but I really think it's an issue with your understanding of computers and javascript and how languages execute. You should really do more homework and try to follow the logic of your script. Simple debugging tools such as `alert("I'm resetting the values now!")` would tell you when your code is executing (whether it's in the right place or not)

---

Nowhere in your code does it actually try to clear the text. These would be some instructions to tell the browser to reset/erase the content. I'm guessing you want to clear it only when it's correct so you would add it to the `.ajaxForm`  callback

```
var name = $('input[name=name]').val(''); //inputs are like this <input value="Hi">
var email = $('input[name=email]').val('');
var message = $('textarea[name=message]').html(''); //textareas are like this <textarea>Hi</textarea>
```

And by the way, fadeOut only makes it "fade out", it ends up hiding the block (css display: none; I'm guessing), but doesn't change the DOM element/form.

Comment: Hello, I tried this before, but it is not working. Maybe I am not putting them in the right place... ?

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga yea you're probably putting it in the wrong place. Add an `alert("Hi");` or something to see if it's actually being called when you want it to. You haven't actually specified when you want it to be cleared; I'm assuming you want to clear it as it's fading out? (dunno if you have it reappear later)

Answer (score 1):

Use the .val() function to clear the values of text , and the html() function to clear the 
Also, it would be easier to manipulate in jQuery if you give each input an ID.

For example, create a form like this:

```
<form method="post" id="frmMessage" action="some_script.php">
<input type="text" name="name" id="txtName" />
<input type="text" name="email" id="txtEmail" />
<textarea name="message" id="txtMessage"></textarea>
</form>
```

Then in your jQuery code:

```
$("#frmMessage").ajaxForm( function()
{
    // Do whatever else you need to do first...
    // Fade out the form's container


    $("#txtName").val('');   // Clear the value of each box.
    $("#txtEmail").val('');  
    $("#txtMessage").html('');   // Different for textareas!

});
```

Comment: I updated the content. but it still doesn't work. I tried also with your code. Any suggestions? Maybe I am not putting them where I have to...

Comment: Have you checked your error console to make sure the Javascript is not hitting an error somewhere else that's preventing this code from executing?  In Firefox, you can press CTRL-SHIFT-J to show the error console.  Then refresh the page and re-run the script.  
Also, I find it helpful to put 'alert()' functions in at key points to verify that my code is actually reaching that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the input values as blank when the value is submitted.

Eg,
var name = $('input[name=name]').val(' ');

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#form")[0].reset();
```

this could help