# How to clear input data after form submit

Tags: jquery, forms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can't clear the input value after form is submited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635116/cant-clear-the-input-value-after-form-is-submited)

Ok, so I tried a 100 times. I need to clear input data after validation and submitting the form. Then the wrapper div will fade out.  So, validate, submit, clear data, fade out. I have a feeling that I don't put the val('') in the right place. If anyone wants to help.. thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#form1').ajaxForm({
        beforeSubmit: validate
    });

    function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
        var name = $('input[name=name]').fieldValue();
        var email = $('input[name=email]').fieldValue();
        var message = $('textarea[name=message]').fieldValue();

        if (!name[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for name');
            return false;
        }
        if (!email[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for email');
            return false;
        }
        if (!message[0]) {
            alert('Please enter a value for message');
            return false;
        }
    }

    var name = $('input[name=name]').val('');
    var email = $('input[name=email]').val('');
    var message = $('textarea[name=message]').html('');

    $("#form1").ajaxForm(function () {
        $("#formplic").fadeOut(1000, function () {
            $(this).html("<img src='images/postauto2.png'/>").fadeIn(2000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You may be interested in reading up on `form.reset()` (this is native - not jquery. form is a reference to the `<form>` element).

Comment: Didn't you [just ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635116/cant-clear-the-input-value-after-form-is-submited) and get several answers?

Comment: shouldn't you put     `var name = $('input[name=name]').val('');` inside the `validate` function? also for textarea you should `val()` instead of `html()`

Comment: @MrOBrian Yes, but no answer worked. So i chaged something in my code and asked again... hope this did not violate stack rules

Comment: You are clearing the fields on document.ready, but the answers to your previous question told you to put those lines of code inside the `.ajaForm` callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove these lines:

```
var name = $('input[name=name]').val('');
var email = $('input[name=email]').val('');
var message = $('textarea[name=message]').html('');
```

and try this:

```
function validate(formData, jqForm, options) {
    //.....Some code.....
    if (!message[0]) {
        alert('Please enter a value for message');
        return false;
    }
    //....Added code....
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('input,textarea','#form1').val(''); //clearing inputs
    },1);
    //..................
}
```

Answer (score 2):

By using jQuery's [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function:

```
$("input").each(function (){
    $(this).val() = "";
});
```

Edit: Your fadeIn/fadeOut seems fine.

Comment: there is no need to use `each`.